# ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO posts (username, image, news, subreddit, title) VALUES

Tags: mysql

After creating a post and comment system,  I added image uploading and got this error message

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO posts (username, image, news, subreddit, title) VALUES ('testing1', 'koth.gif' test', 'm', 'Image'). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'test', 'm', 'Image')' at line 1

I tried modifying the order of the INSERT command and also tried fixing it by changing the image upload code. Lastly, I checked to see if the uploads folders permissions were correct. My goal is to get the image to upload with my post.

Code section that is giving me the error:

```
$username = $_SESSION['userID'];
            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['title']);
            $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['content']);
            // Get image name
            $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $target = "uploads/".basename($image);
            //$subreddit = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['subreddit']);
            $subreddit = 'm';
            $posttype = '1';
            if ($title === '' || $content === '') {
                echo '<script>document.getElementById("failure").innerHTML = "<p>Title or post content not entered.</p>";</script>';
            } else {
                // attempt insert query execution
                $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (username, image, news, subreddit, title) VALUES ('$username', '$image' $content', '$subreddit', '$title')";
                if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
                    // echo "Records added successfully.";
                    $msg = 'Post submitted successfully!';
                    echo "<script> window.location.assign('m.php'); </script>";
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing quote and comma

INSERT INTO posts (username, image, news, subreddit, title) VALUES ('testing1', 'koth.gif', 'test', 'm', 'Image')

INSERT INTO posts (username, image, news, subreddit, title) VALUES ('$username', '$image', '$content', '$subreddit', '$title')

Comment: It is more appropriate to close Off-topic: Typo questions than to post an answer.  Stack Overflow has no interest in archiving typo questions because they represent very little value to researchers.  Answering these types of questions makes it harder for Stack Overflow's automated scripts to purge unwanted pages.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a comma and a single quote before `$content`

Comment: This was it. Thanks, I can't believe I missed that typo.

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].